# mongoexport works on local but not on remote server

Tags: mongodb

When I run this code to export my local database, it works well and a file is successfully generated:

```js
mongoexport \
    --host="localhost:27017" \
    -d springDb \
    -c posts \
    --out social.json
```

But when I try to access my remote server with the similar command here:

```js
mongoexport \
    --host="mongodb+srv://clustxxx.xxx.mongodb.net/xxxx" \
    -d socialDeveloper \
    -c posts \
    --out social.json
```

I get this error:

```js
error parsing command line options: error parsing URI from mongodb:///clustxxx.xxx.mongodb.net/xxxx:27017/?replicaSet=mongodb+srv:: error parsing uri: must have at least 1 host
```

What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: Obviously you have a wrong connection string URI, maybe just a typo.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit How is the connection string format supposed to look like please? I got that URL from my mongoDB account. Something like this?  mongodb:///clustxxx.xxx.mongodb.net/xxxx:27017 but it still doesn't work

Comment: See [Connection String URI Format](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/) - difficult to help you with `xxxx`, we don't know what is means. Maybe use provide your string like `mongodb://<my user>:<password>@<host name>:27017/<my DB name>`

Comment: `///` (three slashes) is certainly wrong. Also `/xxxx:27017` looks wrong. Should not be so difficult to read the documentation.